# Ajax based commenting system

Tags: 7, ajax, comments

In Drupal 7 I'm facing one problem, I'm going to implement a *comment system* in that way that it should work as *chatting systems*. I've a content type *Article*, at the end there is a *comment box* where users can leave comments.

If I add a comment to the article it should be showed in every user's browser if they are viewing it, and at the same time they can *debate/talk* about that article without refreshing the page.

It will be real time commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have solved this issue with two modules

1. [**Ajax Comments**](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments)

> Provides ajax comments to Drupal sites (commenting like a social networking sites: Facebook, Google+, vk.com etc).

2. [**Block Refresh**](http://drupal.org/project/block_refresh)

> Block Refresh allows an administrator to configure a block to refresh it's content via 3 different methods: automatically via a timer (eg every 30 seconds) , manually via a 'refresh' link, and once on page load.

You can view the real sample at http://beinghuman.org/.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ajax Comments](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module *AJAXifies comments* - works well and no need to refresh page.

**Ajax Comments**

> Provides ajax comments to Drupal sites (commenting like a social networking sites: Facebook, Google+, vk.com etc).

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch in ajax comments module to allow for time-based refreshing, but it is not yet committed:
https://drupal.org/node/401288

That would allow the usage of just one module alone to achieve the desired functionality.

I wander how you embedded the comments in the block, as I tried both commentsblock and node_comment_block but then they both didn't refresh using block_refresh.